# Statement has no effect (if/else)

Tags: c++

I'm a student who's learning C++ and I can't figure out why this problem is happening and how to fix it. If/else statement is not appearing when I run the program. If you could help me out that would be great, thanks! Also, please excuse what I've written down there, I'm just a student studying at high school. Thanks!

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string password;

    cout<<"=====Login====="<<endl<<endl

    ;cout<<"Masukkan Password: ";

    cin>>password;

    //percabangan if...else

    if (password=="Steven"){

        cout<<endl;"Selamat datang bos!";   

    }else{

        cout<<endl;"Password salah, coba lagi!";

    }

    cout<<"Terimakasih sudah menggunakan aplikasi ini!";

    return 0;
}
```

It's supposed to look like this (the password is changed)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7ESw.jpg

Comment: format you code properly before putting it here and there are many typos in cout statements . that's where your problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected lines:

```
if (password=="Steven"){


cout<<"Selamat datang bos!"<<endl;   


}
else
{

cout<<"Password salah, coba lagi!"<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `cout` statements need repair.

Instead of this:

```
cout<<endl;"Selamat datang bos!";
```

With that inner `;`, that line becomes two separate statements equivalent to:

```
cout<<endl;            // prints an end of line
"Selamat datang bos!"; // this is a valid C/C++ expression, but doesn't have any effect as a statement.
```

In general, the compiler will happily accept a simple expression ending with a semi-colon as a statement. But in this case, it won't do anything.

Change the above to this:

```
cout << "Selamat datang bos!" << endl;
```

There's some similar typos throughout your code you can also fix.

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot to mention, I need to put blank lines in front of each line so the output could look like  this [imgur.com/a/NGoH5Ks]

Answer (score 1):

Actually due to wrong syntax the **if/else** not work. ***cout<<endl;"Selamat datang bos!";*** also in else statement.
Replace *;* with *<*

Replace this:

```
if (password=="Steven"){

    cout<<endl;"Selamat datang bos!";   

}else{

    cout<<endl;"Password salah, coba lagi!";

}
```

with this one :

```
 if (password=="Steven"){

    cout<<endl<<"Selamat datang bos!";   

}else{

    cout<<endl<<"Password salah, coba lagi!";

}
```